# Why the sizeof a string is different in main and in a function?

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo(char str[])
{
    char *str1=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char )*sizeof(str));

    printf("\n str %s  size : %zu  \n",str,sizeof(str));    
}

int main()
{
    char str[]="879879879-=-=-@#$@#$abcd";
    printf("\n str %s  size : %zu  \n",str,sizeof(str));

    foo(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is string length different in `main()` and `foo()`?
This is a simple program in which `main` calls `foo` with `str` — the same `str` which is showing length 25 in `main` 
and in `foo` 8: why?

Output:

```
str 879879879-=-=-@#$@#$abcd  size : 25  
str 879879879-=-=-@#$@#$abcd  size : 8
```

Comment: In the function, `char str[]` is equivalent to `char *str` and the size of a pointer is smaller than the size of the specific string you're playing with.  In the main function, `str` is an array and `sizeof` reports on the size of the array, including the terminal null byte, which means `sizeof(str) == strlen(str) + 1` — inside `main()`.  (Note that you leak memory in `foo()`.)

Comment: might be helpful: http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Answer (score 3):

In this function declaration

```
int foo(char str[]);
```

the parameter declared like an array is adjusted to pointer of type `char *`.

Thus these function declarations

```
int foo(char str[1000]);
int foo(char str[100]);
int foo(char str[1]);
int foo(char str[]);
```

declare the same one function and equivalent to

```
int foo(char *str);
```

As result within the function this expression

```
sizeof(str)
```

yields the size of a pointer of the type `char *`.

Within the main where there is indeed declared an array

```
char str[]="879879879-=-=-@#$@#$abcd";
```

this expression

```
sizeof(str)
```

yields the size of the array.

If you want to allocate memory in the function to store the string that is kept in the array then instead of the operator `sizeof` you should use standard string function `strlen`. For example

```
int foo(char str[])
{
    char *str1 = (char *)malloc( strlen( str ) + 1 );
    strcpy( str1, str );

    // ...
}
```